# Як перекласти self-loathing i self-pity українською одним або двома словами? Потрібний термін

Tags: переклад, from-english, вибір-слова, from-german

Допоможіть, будь ласка, перекласти **self-loathing** одним або двома словами?

Нічого не знайшов на [e2u.org.ua](http://e2u.org.ua), [yenotes.com](http://yenotes.com), і навіть на lingvo, якому я й так не дуже довіряю.

Чи можна його перекласти як поняття, але не як "*ненависть до себе*"?

[Google](https://translate.google.com.ua/#auto/uk/self-loathing) показує "*самовідчуття*", яке очевидно не підходить (бо потрібне не "відчуття", а відповідник до loathing) i "*ненависть до себе*". Останнє дуже довге (6 складів замість 4, 3 слова замість одного або технічно двох).

Я насправді перекладаю з німецької (Selbstmitleid), тому також спробував перекласти **self-pity**, і результати дуже схожі:

[e2u.org.ua](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=self-pity&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on):

> жалість до самого себе

lingvo:

> жалість до (самого) себе, схильність нарікати на долю

Мені потрібно щось коротше і точніше у перекладі.

Чи є "саможаління" або "саможалощі" питомими українськими словами? Не знаходжу їх у словниках. Чи доречно їх вигадати / взяти з масового вжитку?

Comment: То питання про _self-loathing_, чи _self-pity_, чи це дві різні запитання, чи вони якось пов'язані?

Comment: @Sasha вважаєте, треба зробити два різних? Бо нема відповіді ані на перше, ані на друге. Але мені здавалося, що то синоніми.

Comment: Self-loathing (self-hatred) і self-esteem — синоніми? Ой, навряд. По-моєму, це майже протилежні речі. Я хоч не прихильник кожного разу вимагати розділення таких питань, але цього разу, мені здається, варто якщо не розділити, то хоча б чітко пояснити, що Ви питаєте про дві речі відразу (і в назві запитання зазначити обидва слова). Але мені здається, скоро прийде учасник, що часто агітував за розділення подібних питань (я не пам'ятаю на 100%, але це був, здається, bytebuster).

Comment: Оу, перепрошую, я хотів написати, що self-loathing (self-hatred) і self-pity — навряд чи синоніми (але випадково написав «self-loathing (self-hatred) і self-esteem»).

Comment: @Sasha поки просто змінив питання, далі подивимось, дякую. Можемо видалити ці коментарі.

Answer (score 3):

*Ненависть* (а зазвичай *loathing*/*hatred*, що в [*self-loathing*/*self-hatred*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hatred), перекладають як *ненависть*) має частковий синонім *відраза*.

Суб'єктивно мені здається, що *відраза до себе* звучить краще за *ненависть до себе*, а *самовідраза* за *самоненависть*  (хоч варіанти зі словом *ненависть*, здається, частіше зустрічаються в книжках, але варіанти з *відраза* теж, зокрема *самовідраза* є в «Фройд би плакав» Ірени Карпи й журналі «Всесвіт» за 1995 рік).

Answer (score 2):

Якщо є [самокритика](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on), то може бути і *саможаль/саможалість*, і *самоненависть*.

Comment: я так дивлюся, що й саме Selbstmitleid, мабуть, можна перекласти як "співчуття собі" або самоспівчуття.